# Импорт твитов от нескольких пользователей в одной ленте.

Tags: твиттер

Как это реализовать? Есть ли какие-то библиотеки?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [список](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries) библиотек рекомендованных самими разработчиками твиттера. Нужно будет использовать Streaming API для отслеживания твитов данных пользователей. Далее бот пусть либо копирует либо ретвитит их.